# Bootstrap - Possible CSS problem with left menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap v3.3.2 and cannot get my left menu working properly.

This is the full view of the menu.  The the best looking.
[image]

And here is the problem.  You can see that when I click on setting, I can no longer see the "Contact Us" and "User Admin" menu items.  Any advice very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It is difficult to help you without a code example: it can be helpful if you can replicate the issue on jsfiddle.net

Comment: By experience I can tell you that the issue can be caused by negative margins, or y-overflow or the main page container (the one that contains page content plus menu) has a fixed height and is cutting out the menu. 
If you want a better help, please share your code :)

Comment: give us some code